# C++ Calling one function from another

Tags: c++, custom-action

I have a C++ Custom Action Project. I have two functions, `RegProductName` and `GetProductName`.

I call `RegProductName` and it has three possible outcomes. I have these in an if statement that if it is outcome 1 or outcome 2 then i call my second function `GetProductName` but i can't seem to get it working. Can anyone give me an example of calling one function from another please?

```
extern "C" UINT __stdcall RegProductName(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{
AssertSz(FALSE, "debug here");
DebugBreak();

HRESULT hr = S_OK;
UINT er = ERROR_SUCCESS;
char szProductName[MAX_PATH];


hr = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "RegProductName");
ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to initialize");

WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Initialized.");

strcpy(szProductName, Orc_Get_Product_Name());

if(szProductName == "ORCHESTRATOR")
{
    GetProductName();
} 
else if (szProductName == "CORAL")
{
    GetProductName();
}
else 
{
    MsiSetProperty(hInstall, "PRODUCTNAME",  szProductName);
}


LExit:
er = SUCCEEDED(hr) ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
return WcaFinalize(er);
}
```

The error is "Too few arguments in function call when i hover over `GetProductName();`

```
extern "C" UINT __stdcall GetProductName(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
{

HRESULT hr = S_OK;
UINT er = ERROR_SUCCESS;
DWORD Ret;
CHAR *Section = "General";
CHAR szBuffer[MAX_PATH];
CHAR szProductIniFile[MAX_PATH];
char lpszString[MAX_PATH];
int lplValue;


hr = WcaInitialize(hInstall, "GetProductName");
ExitOnFailure(hr, "Failed to initialize");

WcaLog(LOGMSG_STANDARD, "Initialized.");

TCHAR* szValueBuf = NULL;
DWORD cchValueBuf = 0;
UINT uiStat =  MsiGetProperty(hInstall, TEXT("TEMPFOLDER"), TEXT(""), &cchValueBuf);

if (ERROR_MORE_DATA == uiStat)
{
    ++cchValueBuf; 
    szValueBuf = new TCHAR[cchValueBuf];
    if (szValueBuf)
    {
        uiStat = MsiGetProperty(hInstall, TEXT("TEMPFOLDER"), szValueBuf, &cchValueBuf);
    }
}
if (ERROR_SUCCESS != uiStat)
{
    if (szValueBuf != NULL) 
        delete[] szValueBuf;
    return ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
}

strcpy(szProductIniFile,szValueBuf);

Ret = strlen(szProductIniFile);
if(szProductIniFile[Ret-1] != '\\')
   strcat(szProductIniFile,"\\");

strcat(szProductIniFile, "Product.ini");

Ret = GetPrivateProfileString(Section,          // Section Title [General]
                              "PRODUCT_NAME",   // Entry
                              "Orchestrator",   // Default Value
                              szBuffer,         // Address of buffer to read to
                              MAX_PATH,         // Length of buffer
                              szProductIniFile); // .ini file name


if (strlen(szBuffer) == 0)
    strcpy(szBuffer, "ORCHESTRATOR");

if (strlen(szBuffer) >= 3 && (stricmp(szBuffer+strlen(szBuffer)-3,"DEM") == 0))
    lplValue = 1;
else
    lplValue = 0;


MsiSetProperty(hInstall, "PRODUCTNAME",  szBuffer);

LExit:
er = SUCCEEDED(hr) ? ERROR_SUCCESS : ERROR_INSTALL_FAILURE;
return WcaFinalize(er);
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far, along with relevant compiler output.

Comment: Any code to show what your are doing?

Comment: `void FunA () { }
void FunB () { FunA(); }` here you are.

Comment: Maybe you can show us what you have tried, and we can perhaps tell if there is something wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `GetProductName()` function takes an argument `MSIHANDLE hInstall`. You'll need to provide that when calling it. For instance, if you just want to call it with the same handle as `RegProductName()` was called with:

```
GetProductName(hInstall);
```

Comment: This satisfies the language criteria, but is it valid for custom action framework?

Answer (score 2):

This does not compare the string content:

```
if(szProductName == "ORCHESTRATOR")
```

either use `strcmp()` or use `std::string` and `==`:

```
if(szProductName == std::string("ORCHESTRATOR"))
```

Comment: Ok thanks il change that now, I was not too sure If that worked correctly but was trying to get the function first. Thanks..:)

Answer (score 2):

Your GetProductName looks like this:

```
extern "C" UINT __stdcall GetProductName(MSIHANDLE hInstall)
                                         \________________/
                                            The Argument
```

So it needs to take 1 argument, while you are calling it without argumanes at all:

```
getProductName( );
               ^
               |
            nothing is being passed here
```

hence the error you're getting. Based on your code you should probably pass your `hInstall` there:

```
getProductName( hInstall );
```

Answer (score 1):

The `GetProductName` requires one argument of type `MSIHANDLE` whereas you are calling it without any parameter. Try instead

```
GetProductName(hInstall);
```

Answer (score 0):

`GetProductName` is defined as `GetProductName(MSIHANDLE hInstall)`, that means you MUST pass relevant MSIHANDLE as parameter. And that's exactly the error you're getting.
But you're doing `szProductName == "ORCHESTRATOR"` - this is not how you compare strings in C. You seem to lack basic knowledge about C. You should not be writing in C or C++.

Comment: Thanks, I don't no much about C or C++ but i am trying to learn as I go, have a few useful books and was in a rush when i wrote that. Did not think it would work but put it in quickly to post my code. Thanks

Comment: @NC1 jumping head on into complicated framework in foreign language is usually traumatic experience...